# How to insert a new line between different set of lines?

Tags: python, newline

I have a different set of lines like below:

```
L341IQ345S.W99990001;O4;77;1;3.7;2.9;4.3;-6.5;1;0
L341IQ345S.W99990001;O4;77;9;3.7;2.8;3.9;-5.8;1;0
L341IQ345S.W99990001;O4;77;16;3.4;2.8;3.7;-5.5;1;0
L341IQ345S.W99990002;O4;74;1;3.5;2.9;4.1;-6.3;1;0
L341IQ345S.W99990002;O4;74;8;3.7;3.3;2.7;-5.7;1;0
L341IQ345S.W99990003;O2;85;4;3.6;3.0;3.2;-5.7;0;1
L341IQ345S.W99990003;O2;85;6;3.6;3.5;3.0;-5.6;0;1
L341IQ345S.W99990003;O4;85;9;3.4;2.8;3.2;-5.4;1;0
L341IQ345S.W99990003;O4;85;10;3.4;2.7;3.9;-5.4;1;0
L341IQ345S.W99990004;O2;83;5;3.6;3.5;2.7;-5.1;0;1
L341IQ345S.W99990004;O4;83;22;3.1;2.3;3.2;-4.7;1;0
```

where I want to insert a newline before each new set of lines like below:

```
L341IQ345S.W99990001;O4;77;1;3.7;2.9;4.3;-6.5;1;0
L341IQ345S.W99990001;O4;77;9;3.7;2.8;3.9;-5.8;1;0
L341IQ345S.W99990001;O4;77;16;3.4;2.8;3.7;-5.5;1;0

L341IQ345S.W99990002;O4;74;1;3.5;2.9;4.1;-6.3;1;0
L341IQ345S.W99990002;O4;74;8;3.7;3.3;2.7;-5.7;1;0

L341IQ345S.W99990003;O2;85;4;3.6;3.0;3.2;-5.7;0;1
L341IQ345S.W99990003;O2;85;6;3.6;3.5;3.0;-5.6;0;1
L341IQ345S.W99990003;O4;85;9;3.4;2.8;3.2;-5.4;1;0
L341IQ345S.W99990003;O4;85;10;3.4;2.7;3.9;-5.4;1;0

L341IQ345S.W99990004;O2;83;5;3.6;3.5;2.7;-5.1;0;1
L341IQ345S.W99990004;O4;83;22;3.1;2.3;3.2;-4.7;1;0
```

Thanking you in advance

Comment: sorry next time i will try to put my attempts

Comment: There's no "time" here in SO. Anyone could come here from a search on google. Therefore, you should keep being concerned by your past posts' quality. I invite you to edit your question so it can help other readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the lines, iterate through each line identifying the text that should be grouped by, if grouped by text changes add new line :

```
text = "L341IQ345S.W99990001;O4;77;1;3.7;2.9;4.3;-6.5;1;0\n"+"L341IQ345S.W99990001;O4;77;9;3.7;2.8;3.9;-5.8;1;0\n"+"L341IQ345S.W99990001;O4;77;16;3.4;2.8;3.7;-5.5;1;0\n"+"L341IQ345S.W99990002;O4;74;1;3.5;2.9;4.1;-6.3;1;0\n"+"L341IQ345S.W99990002;O4;74;8;3.7;3.3;2.7;-5.7;1;0\n"+"L341IQ345S.W99990003;O2;85;4;3.6;3.0;3.2;-5.7;0;1\n"+"L341IQ345S.W99990003;O2;85;6;3.6;3.5;3.0;-5.6;0;1\n"+"L341IQ345S.W99990003;O4;85;9;3.4;2.8;3.2;-5.4;1;0\n"+"L341IQ345S.W99990003;O4;85;10;3.4;2.7;3.9;-5.4;1;0\n"+"L341IQ345S.W99990004;O2;83;5;3.6;3.5;2.7;-5.1;0;1\n"+"L341IQ345S.W99990004;O4;83;22;3.1;2.3;3.2;-4.7;1;0\n"

print(text)

iter = text.splitlines(False)
lastid = ""
for line in iter:
    id = line[line.find('.')+1:line.find(';')]
    if id != "" and lastid != id:
      print("")
    print(line)
    lastid = id
```

Comment: thankyou somuch and next time I will try to put my attempts

Comment: @Coder Should use a different variable name. `iter` is a built-in function name.

Answer (score 1):

You should at least upload some of the code you've written, or be more specific of what you want. From what I can tell you seem to want to split it based on the second post (the part between the . and the first ;) so I would save that section, then compare it to the next line. If that line does not match, just append a newline '\n' to the string, get the new section of the new line, and repeat.